# Как поставить с docker - php7 mongo apache

Tags: apache, mongodb, php7

Никогда не пользовался докером.

Как поставить PHP 7 с драйвером для mongodb и модулем apache, чтобы каждый в своем докер контейнере был.

И главное как потом это в связку связать чтобы заработало?

Comment: Хотелось бы конкретизировать вопрос. Конкретно по сборке достаточно просто взять изображение php:7-apache и установить mongodb из pecl.

Answer (score 4):

Если не хотите углубляться в докер и быстро начать, советую поставить сразу 
https://docs.docker.com/compose/ .
После чего вам достаточно использовать следуюдий docker-compose.yml + Dockerfile (чтобы довить pecl extension в php) в корне вашего проекта:

**docker-compose.yml**

```
    web:
      build: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      links: ["mongo"]
      ports: 
       - "80:80"
      volumes: 
       - .:/var/www/html
#создайте папку logs предварительно
      environment:
       - APACHE_LOG_DIR=./logs
    mongo:
      image: mongo
      ports:
       - "27017:27017"
```

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM php:7.0.6-apache   
# копируем ваш кастомный виртуал хост, по желанию
ADD /path/to/your/apache2.conf /etc/apache2/apache2.conf  

RUN  apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
  libssl-dev \
  && a2enmod rewrite \
  && pecl install mongodb \
  && docker-php-ext-enable mongodb
```

А потом docker-compose up -d и всё.
Если будут ошибки - пишите, отвечу в комментариях